Cursor/Visual Studio files suddenly empty
When I open my cursor/vscode react native project first of all my IDE is lagging a little. The files seem to load longer than they were 1 week ago. Also when I click on some files they are suddenly empty. In the file explorer they are not empty though.
When i restart the IDE and wait a little previous empty files have code again. But some other files don't. Also different file imports like "import "AudioWaves" from "./../components/AudioWaves.tsx" don't work suddenly. Whenever I fix the file-url/route, it works again. Everytime I open the project this happens. It has been like this for a few days. It's stressing me out.
Does it have something to do with cache or RAM. I have an 8GB Apple Macbook with an M2 -chip.
I tried to find a solution but nothing seems to work.
